# Firebase Cloud Messaging returning InvalidApnsCredential despite valid P8 APNs Auth Key existing

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to an IOS device using Firebase Cloud Messaging - every IOS project in the Firebase Console has a valid APNs P8 Auth Key, freshly generated from the Apple developer account for this purpose.

I’m using this approach:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -H 'Authorization: key=<My Key>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "to": "<Device Token>",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Push Notification Test to IOS",
        "body":"Push Notification Test to IOS"
    },
    "data": {
        "message": "Push Notification Test to IOS"
    }
}'
```

This results in the following error from FCM:

```
{
    "multicast_id": <Id>,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidApnsCredential"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove the "notification" block from the message, FCM responds with a success, but nothing is received on the device.

I can send and receive notifications using the above example message to 
Android devices just fine.

The [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) suggests that when a "notification" block is included, FCM attempts to send via APNs when the token is for an IOS device:

> If a notification payload is provided, or the content_available option is set to true for a message to an iOS device, the message is sent through APNs, otherwise it is sent through the FCM connection server.

What I have tried:

- Refreshing the tokens
- Waiting 24 hours for tokens to propagate in APNs and FCM server environments
- using P12 certificates
- using P8 certificates
- ensured the IOS app is allowing notifications in Xcode
- ensured the Apple Developer account has the app as allowing notifications
- ensured the Bundle Ids are correct in the plist, FCM and Apple account
- tried both the FCM legacy key and server key

Comment: Does the Team ID of the APNs Authentication key match the Team ID of the app?

Comment: @JenPerson yes.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution @Moo? I'm experiencing the same problem here.

Comment: @Moo Did you find out what was causing the issue? I also pretty much followed and tried everything you mentioned above. Still getting the same error. Revoked and used a new Auth key 3 times, and that didn't work.

Comment: Same problem here @Moo, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidApnsCredential` doesn't means the issue is directly related to the APNS certificate nor the key.

I my case, I faced this problem with a white labeled app & after investigation, I found that my app bundle id (PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) was not matching the one in Firebase (I was using a development bundle id instead of the production one).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Bundle ID is correct.

If it's not the same, create a new iOS app (**Configuration** → **General** → **Add an app**) and make sure to set the name correctly.

In my case, I had the shortest version of the bundle ID (`com.company`) instead of the long one (`com.company.appname`).

Doing this you should **not** need to re-compile and re-upload the app.